# how to preserve electron's default exception window after catching the exception?

Tags: error-handling, electron, onerror

I am catching electron application's errors with `window.onerror` and logging that to file, and I find the alert popup with brief stacktrace helpful, but with `onerror` that alert goes away.

How to preserve the default alert box while doing a custom handler?

Comment: reason to close?